# OData client v3 to v4 update approach for Expand object of collection

Tags: c#, vb.net, odata, odata-v4

From some thirdparty we use the backend which been updated from OData v3 to v4. That means we have to update our software as well.

Now the problem i'm facing is that the way collections work are different in v4 than they where in v3. For example, the code i used to `GET ~/OData/Orders` and also the `OrderItems` and in the `OrderItems` collection expand the object Product was:

```
SomeDataServiceContext.Orders.Expand("OrderItems").Expand("OrderItems/Product").Take(10)
```

Now with OData v4 i can expand the `OrderItems`, but the expand of the Product object within the `OrderItems` collection don't work anymore. This is the code i now use:

```
SomeDataServiceContext.Orders.Expand(Function(x) x.OrderItems).Take(10)
```

But as you can see this does retrieve the collection of `OrderItems` but don't expand the Product object within the `OrderItems` collection. The `OrderItems` Collection however does contain the property `ProductId`

So in this case what would be the right approach:

1. Find if there is a new way in v4 to get nested Expands
2. Query Endpoint `SomeDataServiceContext.Products` to get the corresponding product
3. Suggestions?

My knowledge about OData is beginner to medium level, so be gentle ;-)

Comment: The server and client have to be compatible. Updating the server to new version may solve issue. Talk to the people maintaining the server to see if they have recommendations.

Comment: It's the server that has been updated to v4. Now we have to update our client from v3 to v4

Comment: C# or VB? you've tagged both, which language do you want the solution in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the client there is lambda syntax support for nested expansions only if the link is singluar, as `Order.OrderItems` is a *collection* you can use the string variant of the expand method:

```
SomeDataServiceContext.Orders.Expand("OrderItems($expand=Product)").Take(10)
```

> You will notice here, expansion syntax is one of the breaking changes in URL parsing between OData v3 and v4.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for and saved me lot of time to convert my code. I only had to update the query string and now everything works like a charm! :-)